# jQuery blockUI only showing the first time it's called

Tags: jquery, blockui

I am using blockUI with some AJAX calls and am running into issues with it working.  The first time it is called everything works as expected.  When I execute a subsequent AJAX call and try to call blockUI it does not block my screen again.  In both cases writing to console results in function (opts) { install(window, opts); } being returned.  Thinking that it might be a z-value issue I've tried adding baseZ with a number higher than any other z-value in my css but that didn't correct it.  A simple instance of one of the calls is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',".defect",function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: "<h4>Getting images ...</h4><img src='img/wait.gif'/>"});
    })
})
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent idea: block ui while making non-blocking request :)

Answer (score 0):

To use blockui, you must "unblock" the blockui after the ajax call (callback) like this:

```
$.blockUI({ message: "<h1><img src='imgs/ajax-loader2.gif' > zzzzz...</h1>" }); 
$.ajax({ url: myurl.php, type: 'POST',async:true,  dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(msg){
        $.unblockUI(); 
    },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText);}
});
```

(async MUST be true)
I read as an alternative you can use:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

but I do prefer to manage it by my own.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was using  (document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);  I tried removing that and $.unblockUI(); in my AJAX success but still had the same results.  Any other thoughts?